# Kali installer not recognizing Windows partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, kali-linux

I was trying to install Linux (Kali) alongside with my Windows 8.1 (64bit) but i couldn't because Linux can't detect any partition or unallocated space of my disk.Even GParted shows my entire disk as a 250gb unallocated space! I think the problem is from my disk or partition table but i don't know how to fix it? Help please.

Comment: You say that Linux can't find any unallocated space but GParted sees the entire drive as unallocated space?  And are you referring to the entire physical drive that Windows is on, everything except the Windows partitions on that drive, or a separate drive?

Comment: Yes exactly!I mean Linus just allows to install on entire disk and it doesn't show any of my partitions.Windows partitions are on that drive

Comment: I described two conflicting statements and three different scenarios, and your response was "Yes exactly", so the situation is a bit confusing.  Can you add some detail to your question to describe your drives and partitions, and exactly what happens with GParted and the Linux installer?  BTW, Kali isn't one of the distros I've installed, but I've never seen one that offered only the option of installing on the entire disk, and GParted should be able to prepare the drive as desired.  Is your system UEFI?